# Specifying parameter pack length with concepts

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is a snippet based on [Daisy Hollman's talk](https://youtu.be/15etE6WcvBY?t=3306)

```
#include<utility>
using std::size_t;

template<typename, size_t>
concept any = true;

template<size_t N>
auto invokeN(auto f, auto... args) {
    return [&]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return [&](any<Is> auto..., auto n, auto...) {
            return f(n);
        }(args...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

auto x = invokeN<2>([](auto x){ return x; }, 42., "420", 4200);  // 4200
```

Which supposedly uses `Is` to specify the length of the first parameter pack and makes the remaining parameters deducible.

Is this legal? [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/orTzMYPK7) and [clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/aGdGe9zb5) seems to be choking on this left and right. [clang 15](https://godbolt.org/z/5nrTc8aoK) and lower seems to compile fine.

Comment: I can't find myself willing to blame any C++ compiler for choking on this. This is People's Exhibit A of why C++ has gotten out of hand.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Amen to that (...)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Actually, [clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/xh6vzc8z8) crashes when the index is out of bounds. So, yeah... the compiler authors have my sympathies.

Comment: Is it clear that this is should actually be working? She seems to talk about "if you want to see things like this in the standard" at the end but I'm not 100% sure if it's this particular example she's talking about.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think she meant this snippet is legal, but her snippet doesn't compile due to typos.

Comment: @PasserBy Aha...